# JSONException not caught

Tags: android, jsonexception

I have this piece of code:

```
HJRestClient.post(path, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("tags");
                if (adDetailViewAdapter != null) {
                    adDetailViewAdapter.setTags(array);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

It is crashing on the line `JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("tags");` with exception `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tags`

While I have written code for catching the exception, it's not getting caught and causing the app to crash.

I have 2 devices Samsung Galaxy Note 5 with `Android v6.0.1` in which the `exception` is caught successfully.

Another Huawei Mate 7 with `Android v4.4.2` in which the `exception` is not getting caught and causing a crash.

I also wrote:

```
catch (Exception exception) {}
```

but still it's getting crashed.

Any help?

Comment: put your json response also to verify

Comment: if you are getting your response null than it will raise exception. in your case it looks like your are getting response but you are fetching wrong tag (value) from your response.

Comment: Have you considered using `optJSONArray` instead? :)

Comment: If the response is null it will raise a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should this way:

```
HJRestClient.post(path, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                if(response!=null&&response.has("tags")){
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("tags");
                    if (adDetailViewAdapter != null) {
                        adDetailViewAdapter.setTags(array);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I wrote your code and now its crashing but without showing the exception type.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer, Edited my answer, please check

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It turned out there was a bug in code for Grid adapter where the tags were used. Android studio was not showing the correct exception but Crashlytics showed Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
       at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1046)

Comment: @AbdullahUmer, Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, even if I wrapped the json parse method inside try catch, it was never catching the exception. So I explicitly added

```
 catch (e: Exception) {
        when (e) {
            is SomeExceptionType -> {
                throw MyException()
            }
            is JSONException -> {
                throw BackendErrorException("Something is coming wrong from the server!")
            }
            else -> throw e
        }
    }
```